# Set minimum Slice Width in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying highcharts API to draw input data graphically. Below is the link to JS fiddle

[PIE CHART FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/68/)

Herein i am facing one issue that 1% looks so small and it will be difficult to click while on mobiles.

Is there any way to make the width of `1% as of 2%` and `2% as of 3%`, 3% as of 4%` and so on.

I tried by increasing inner size but PIE looks too big that way.

Comment: The easiest way I'm aware of would be to alter your data before feeding it into the chart.

Comment: alter you data means??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16921463/2134604

Comment: IMHO, the best would be to display value in the `dataLabel`: http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/69/ - so user doesn't have to navigate chart to read values. Also, when hovering `dataLabels` you get tooltip displayed.

Comment: @PawełFus ... tooltip is the thing that is not desired in project.

Comment: So maybe tell us what is desired? ;) As I said, without modifying data or wrapping some Highcharts code it's not so simple. Still if you need click event, dataLabel will work: http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/70/