# How can i manage column height if one column has less data compared to other column in a series

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have problem of manage minPointLength of a series when it has less data compare to other columns
here is my code

```
{
  
  "xAxis": {
     "categories": ["abcd", "efgh"],
    
  },
  
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "colors": ["#2F4668", "#00BF13"],
  "tooltip": {},
  
  "series": [{
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series1",
    "turboThreshold": 4,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 12765433.5
     
    }, {
      "name": "efgh",
      "y": 12.45
      
    }],
 
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series2",
    "turboThreshold": 1,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 15.2
    }],
 
  }],
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "animation": false,
      "events": {}
    },
    "column": {
      "pointPadding": 0,
      "groupPadding": 0.3,
    
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "borderRadius": 2
    }
  }
}
```

i have tried it with minPointLength: 3 but this is breaking when we have data value is zero i was displaying the value of data on chart. ideally it should not.
Image for reference:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zLe5.png)

Comment: If you don't want to show 0 values, the best and easiest solution is to change them to nulls, as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uf3a7wb0/

Comment: Thanks for solution and it is working fine for me.

@magdalena now i need to handle this situation(How can i manage column height if one column has less data compared to other column in a series) for pie chart as we know `minPointLength` property is not working with Pie series

Comment: Goo to hear that! In case of the pie I would recommend to take a look at the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921212/pie-piece-too-small